# iphone html page - open link in safari when viewed with UIWebVIew

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a local html page (saved on the router) with an agree button to connect to a local WiFi system and a redirect to our website. When you connect to the WiFi system, you automatically get to this page. But the problem is that in some cases the page is opened with UIWebView.

So when you click the agree button in UIWebView, you get connected but the redirect doesn't work, because UIWebView closes and safari is not opened.

If you click on the agree button in safari, everything works fine.

I found a code to open links in safari from a UIWebView application.

```
NSURL* url = [request URL];
if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    return NO;
}
```

But this is a html page and i have no idea how to use that.

So does anybody know how to open the link in safari IF VIEWED with UIWEB?

Our html button code looks like this:

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="http://111.111.1.1:5280/">
<input type="hidden" name="accept_terms" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.oursite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="mode_login">
<input type="image" src="img/AGREE.png" alt="Agree">
</form>
```

THANX

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your string/url"];
```

To open link in Safari copy this function in your class:

```
 - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType 
{
   // NSLog(@"shouldStartLoadWithRequest Loading: %@", [request URL]);
   return TRUE;

}
```

Hope this helps..